# how to display sql process using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

i developed a calculation using asp.net.According to some process it get some times.(Bcoz of sql data reading).

I want to load sql data (eg:user id) to asp.net page while sql process ia running.I try do in this using label.but it is not working.

In other way, i'm trying to do real time data loading.Is it possible?..

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible just you need to add the code in your web.config file and run the application it will prompt you the loading time(Per Page basis) just after page rendering. Scroll the mouse down and get the details.

```
 <system.web>

        <trace pageOutput="true" requestLimit="10" enabled="true" localOnly="true"        traceMode="SortByTime" mostRecent="true"/>

</system.web>
```

Note: you need to write the trace part of the code in system.web which already exists in your web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

With this query I suppose you can choose data that you need:

```
SELECT   st.text, r.session_id, r.status, r.command, r.cpu_time, r.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS st
```

If you know required session Id you can add to query:

`WHERE r.session_id = <spid number>`

Here `<spid number>` is your session id.